# Simplest Htaccess for Redirecting index.php/html and non-www To www Root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What is the simplest way to redirect index.php, index.html and non-www variants to the www root with .htaccess? For example redirecting

```
http://example.com/index.php
http://www.example.com/index.html
http://example.com
```

to http://www.example.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this redirects index.html and index.php to root? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah it will. The $1 backlinks to anything after the trailing slash.

Comment: Ah, sorry reading it again I can see what you mean. You will just need to add another `RewriteRule` if you distinctly want to redirect from a specific page. But if `index.html` is setup as a default page anyway then it won't matter, it will still end up in the same place.