# .htaccess redirect from every index.html in anywhere to www/index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site say like this:

```
images / index.html  
images/nav / index.html  
styles/ index.html  
styles/images/ index.html  
js/ index.html 
index.php
```

I want to use .htaccess rewrite module to redirect from every index.html anywhere in site to index.php

here is what I tested but not get me to the desired result:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ index.php [NC,R]
```

any hep would be appreciated

Comment: I have found a similar post [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060680/simplest-htaccess-for-redirecting-index-php-html-and-non-www-to-www-root) but I dont know how to implement it in my case

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html?$ %1/index.php [L,R,NC]
```